# Bootstrap input fixed px width unless small screen then width 100%

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap, I want to have form fields/inputs that are 200px wide, unless the screen < 768px/viewed on a smart phone, then I want the form fields to be 100% width.

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group responsive200">
    <label for="email">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
  </div>
</form>
```

I made this CSS, but the input stays width:200px when screen is small.

```
.responsive200 {
    width:200px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .responsive200 { width:100%; }
}
```

How do I have my input be width:200px unless screen < 768px, then width:100%?

Comment: change `min-width` to `max-width` ... [see if that does it](https://jsfiddle.net/n9a6kvw3/)

Comment: @zgood  I made that change but mine doesn't jump to 100% width on page in my localhost like your jsfiddle does.

Comment: it seems to work in the fiddle I linked. Move the fiddle frame window back and forth and the textbox will be 200px when the frame is wider than 768 and will be 100% if less than

Comment: "I made this CSS, but the input stays width:200px when screen is small." - This is what you expected right? Do you want to implement the same in bootstrap? Looks like the css works as expected.

Comment: @AndrewKoper try inspecting the `div.responsive200` when the screen is small and see if the style is getting overridden. I suspect that the style in the `@media` query probably needs to be more specific. (i.e. `form .someParent .responsive200 { width: 100%; }`. You could also try putting an `!important;` on the `@media` style

Comment: @Siva I am using responsive/Bootstrap, but I want to override Bootstrap's default behavior: I don't want the input to be width:100% all of the time.

Comment: 1. I can see the width of the input field is 200px when checking in small screens.
2. And 100% if the screen width is more than 768px

Comment: can you please provide plunker url which shows this issue?

Comment: Jesus C****, the Internet is so frustrating sometimes.  My responsive200 class was not being overridden when the screen was small.  In my CSS sheet, I had the @media query defined ahead of the responsive200 class, but I transposed those two things when I posted this SO question because I thought it would be clearer.  I just changed my CSS so that the responsive200 class is defined AHEAD of the media query (with max-width), and this worked

Comment: @zgood: will you please make your change to my CSS nad post as an answer?  I'll check it as the correct one. Siva: you comment made me check the css specificity again - thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your `@media` condition to his:

```
.responsive200 {
    width:200px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .responsive200 { width:100%; }
}
```

It should work for you

Comment: Other programmers: it is important that the fixed-width rule is defined ahead of the media query rule.

Answer (score 0):

You have it the wrong way around. Your media query applies the style to anything wider than 768px.

Bootstrap's grid system by default starts off with mobile (smallest device) first and then applies styles as the screen gets wider.

Try this:

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
.responsive200 {
    width:100%;
}

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */  
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .responsive200 { width:200px; }
}
```

For reference check out Bootstrap [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries).